# Firebase Firestore Android Deleting Multiplayer Game Documents

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a game where two devices/users are connected to a firestore Game document. At the end of the game, I load the game results to both users and then they move on to another game. My issue right now is thinking of the best way of deleting completed game objects. Once a game is completed it no longer needs to be in firestore. I just tested putting `gameDocRef.delete()` for both users at the end but then occasionally one player deletes it too fast and the other can't load the results.

Is there a better/automated way of cleaning up completed documents? Maybe Firebase Functions or something? Any advice is apprectiated :)

Comment: How do you define the exact moment when the document should be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could store two values; eg. "player one acknowledged" & "player two acknowledged",

in order to confirm, when both of the players had fetched the results of the game -

and delete only those documents, where both of them had acknowledged

(possibly even with a Cloud Functions cleanup script, instead of the client).

a) when looking at the [events](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore) available, the update trigger would appear the most suitable:

```
providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.update
```

with the downside, that it would be triggered quite often, because it is per document and not per field.

b) alternatively, one could batch the deletions, triggering via HTTP, with a cronjob on another host .

[here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) would be an example, using App Engine Cron (as alternative to Linux `crontab` on GCE).

Comment: In addition, players acknowledgement could be confirmed when they move on to a new screen/activity also have a listener there so when both bool value = true then delete. This way it will only trigger when last of the 2 players have exited the document activity/screen.

Comment: @CRey think that deleting later on would be better, because there is a small chance, but it is not entirely impossible, that they move on in exactly the same moment. having a bunch of these acknowledged documents in backlog, wouldn't hurt.

Comment: That would be my approach too: make acknowledgement a phase in your gameplay, and only delete when both players reach that state, instead of when the actual gameplay ends. You could do this either in Cloud Functions or in the client, whatever you feel more comfortable with. Either way: listen for the state of both players, and delete when both have acknowledged.

Comment: I kind of did it like this answer. I have joinerDone and creatorDone fields in the game and players update them after they are done getting the results. Once both fields are true, then both players attempt to delete the game. This will successfully delete documents 99.9% of the time I'm guessing.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I see what you mean. I absolutely agree with you. May I suggest maybe an hourly clean up or daily clean up would be better based on both bool values being true. Or even when next game starts, trigger the deletion. The docs then will be deleted by either player's next game.